# Was the C++14 standard defective/underspecified w.r.t. deduction of an array type function parameter from an initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

It comes as no surprise that the following program

```
// #1
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void f(T (&&)[N]) {}

int main() { f({1,2,3}); }
```

is seemingly well-formed in C++14 (well, at least all compilers that I've tried seems to accepts it).

However, it seems as if this is not supported by the C++14 standard, particularly that `T` and `N` can be deduced from an initializer list argument?

[[temp.deduct.type]/3.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.type#3.4)

> A given type `P` can be composed from a number of other types,
> templates, and non-type values:
>
> - [...]
> - /3.4 An array type includes the array element type and the value of the array bound.

explains why deduction succeeds for the following example:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void f(T (&)[N]) {}

int main() { 
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};  // #2
    f(arr);
}
```

where particularly [[dcl.init.aggr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#4) governs that `#2` declares and array of size `3` (even though omitted from the type in the declaration).

However, in the context of a function call, as per [[temp.deduct.type]/5.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.type#5.6)

> A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the parameter does not have `std::initializer_list` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list` type.

... this is a non-deduced context.

From the C++17 standard and onwards [[temp.deduct.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#1) has been updated to express that an array type argument can be deduced from a (non-empty) initializer list, but this [was not present in the C++14 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.call), and [[temp.deduct.type]/5.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.6), regarding non-deduced contexts, explicitly refers to [temp.deduct.call]/1 for exceptions to the rule.

Was this a defect/underspecification of the C++14 standard?

- If so, is there an associated defect report<sup>(1)</sup>?
- If not, what passages of the C++14 standard covers that `#1` above is well-formed?

<sub>(1) I've tried to find one myself without any success.</sub>

Comment: [`git log -G'argument is a non-empty initializer list'`](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1591)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That's it, thanks! Would you like to provide an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [DR 1591](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1591).

> It would seem reasonable ... to allow an array bound to be
> deduced from the number of elements in the initializer list, e.g.,
>
> ```
>   template<int N> void g(int const (&)[N]);
>   void f() {
>     g( { 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
>   }
> ```

Being a DR, it applies retroactively to C++14.

---

<sup>NB: It seems [Language Lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9585016) [beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69086319/was-the-c14-standard-defective-underspecified-w-r-t-deduction-of-an-array-typ#comment122102589_69086319), but I found it independently through [git blame](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blame/3cee0dee7785e79145b660364d4b8244086a5df4/source/templates.tex#L7339) of `templates.tex`:)</sup>